# Magento 2 CSV Import Error

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-csv

I'm trying to import customers to a Magento 2 website. Data validation is OK (File is valid! To start import process press "Import" button), but when I click on import button  I get error.

[image: Maximum error count has been reached or system error.]

Comment: Please click in the `Download Full Report`, this will download the CSV file you are trying to upload. When you will open the file you will find a new column added at the end, named `errors`, it should contain the possible error message of why import is throwing an error

Comment: I already download this report but after open CSV file , not shows any mesage in error coloumn.it blank formate.

Comment: Export current product CSV and compare them to check if the format are the same

Comment: I have created some custom import, the uploaded file is a success after that I got a button named "Import" if I hit the button nothing is happening.there is no request sent when I hit the button. i have followed the http://www.blogtreat.com/how-to-import-csv-file-to-custom-module-table-in-magento-2/#comment-1309